# Import csv file having symbol with trailing space to KDB table

Tags: csv, kdb

The following is the content of a csv file I exported from a KDB table. There is a trailing space in the value `Z`  of `rootTicker` column.

```
time,rootTicker,session,yellowKey
2020-08-04D03:46:16.501844000,Z ,,Index
```

When I tried to import this file back to KDB, the trailing space is trimmed.

```
q)TestTable:("psss";enlist csv)0:`TestTable.csv
q)string select from TestTable
time                            rootTicker session yellowKey
------------------------------------------------------------
"2020.08.04D03:46:16.501844000" ,"Z"       ""      "Index"
```

If I export the table into binary format, it can preserve the trailing space when I import it back. Is there anyway to import csv file and no space is trimmed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JD says, read it in as a string rather than a symbol:

```
("p*ss";enlist csv)0:
```

Kdb will always trim whitespace when casting to symbol

```
q)string`$"Z "
,"Z"
```

The only way to avoid it is to manipulate bytecode but you don't want to go there:

```
q)string -9!0x010000000c000000f55a2000
"Z "
```

Answer (score 2):

Loading in as a Char will preserve the space however this space will be lost if it is ever required as a string.

```
q)string `$"abc "
"abc"
```

whereas we have

```
q)`char$"abc "
"abc "
```